# Is there a word that means 'causes/causing evolution?'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

For example

The thunderstone is a *evolution-ing* or *evolv-ifying* substance. It causes some thunder type pokemon to evolve.

Comment: "catalyst" doesn't mean causing evolution but may be useful.

Comment: 'Evolutionogenic' has been used. Once, apparently.

Comment: "Evolvogenic" (noun: "Evolvogen") could be a fitting neologism.

Answer (score 4):

The thunderstone is a **mutagen** and it's effects are **mutagenic**.

mutagen:

> an agent (as a chemical or various radiations) that tends to increase the frequency or extent of mutation.

"Mutagen." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 11 Sept. 2016.

mutagenic:

> :  inducing or capable of inducing genetic mutation

"Mutagenic." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 11 Sept. 2016.

Comment: +1. For evolution in general, i.e., change, this is the right word.

Answer (score 3):

Why not *[phylogenic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/phylogeny?q=phylogenic#phylogeny__5)*? *Oxford Dictionaries Online* defines *[phylogenesis](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/phylogenesis#phylogenesis__2)* as

> The evolutionary development and diversification of a species or group of organisms, or of a particular feature of an organism.

Comment: I don't know this word, but from the description it sounds like this refers to the evolution itself, i.e. the result rather than the cause the OP is looking for.

Comment: @MrLister If you need more explicit causation, you could craft *phylogenefactory* or *phylogenefacious*.

Answer (score 1):

It's an evolution inducing substance. It induces the evolution.

> *induce* to cause something to happen [-Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/induce)

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. I edited your answer to have it use an actual link and to a format more commonly used when citing dictionaries.